# iTunes sync complaining about songs that don't exist

Tags: iphone, ipad, data-synchronization, music

I had an album in Music ripped from an MP3 CD.  Creator had "titled" the tracks with numbers.  The import changed them to .m4a

I exited from Music, changed the tags, including the album name, and converted all from .m4a to .mp3

Opened music, went to the album, and deleted all the songs.  Imported them again from the changed files.

Now, the old song titles and the old album name cannot be found in Music.  But when I sync an iPad or iPhone, I get a pop-up saying some songs were not copied because they cannot be played on this iPad, including (**former** title of the last song in the album).

In Get Info, I edited the titles and other attributes of the last four songs in the album (hoping that would set some kind of "change" flag), but I still get the pop-up with the original wrong title.

The entire album with the original wrong tags is still visible in the iPad.  the new one is not.  I tried turning off "sync music" and it said it would delete all songs from the iPad.  It did not do that!  Tried unchecking the album and playlist and syncing, then rechecking.  Didn't help.

***Is there some way to fix this?***

Comment: Sync iPad with Mac or PC including music. On Mac or PC open iTunes and select the "ghost" entries. Delete them. If iTunes asks to move the files to the trash say no. Apple expects users to not know how to do this stuff so if you try a common sense work around the software gets confused. Annoying but once you get the hang of "The Apple Way" it will start to make sense. That is if I have understood what is going on here...

Comment: I did sync including (after excluding).  ITunes is old news.  The library has been converted to Music.  Besides, if they aren’t visible in the library, they can’t be selected.  And if they were visible, I would want to move them to the trash.

Comment: Odd, when I convert files in iTunes/Music to AAC it shows both copies in the main window and I just delete the old AIFF files, leaving the AAC versions to do with as I please. You should do **ZERO** renaming of files outside of iTunes/Music. That way leads to madness. Import the songs, make any changes you need **IN** the program, convert to MP3 (or whatever), delete the old songs. All inside iTunes/Music. Your second step is the problem here.

Comment: I did not rename the files.  I corrected the wrong titles, and before importing the modified (NOT renamed) files into Music (NOT iTunes), deleted the old ones.  This was not the first time I did something similar, but it is the first time that (1) sync failed to mirror the removal and (2) failed to mirror the new import.